# Special characters not returned correctly from database usingJdbcTemplate

Tags: oracle, jdbc, character-encoding, char, spring-jdbc

In the Data Base the Value of AptNumber = 1º but when use select query it is returning AptNumber  = 1ﾺ , so in selct the `º` changing to `ﾺ`.

Aplication: Spring Batch
Using: JdbcTemplate to connect DB
Data BAse: Oracle
Querty : select APT_NBR from CUST_ADDR WHERE CUST_ADDR_ID=12345;

Comment: What do you get by `select DUMP(APT_NBR, 1016) from CUST_ADDR WHERE CUST_ADDR_ID=12345;`?

Comment: What is the character set of your database? Check by by `SELECT * 
    FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
    WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';`

Comment: Strange, if you would get `슺` ([U+C2BA](https://codepoints.net/U+C2BA) HANGUL SYLLABLE SEUJ) then I would say: Your DB stores character as UTF-8 (resp. `AL32UTF8`) but your java is set to `UTF-16`

Comment: select DUMP(APT_NBR, 1016) from CUST_ADDR WHERE CUST_ADDR_ID=12345, giving results     "Typ=1 Len=2 CharacterSet=US7ASCII: 31,ba"

Answer (score 0):

`º` is character [U+00BA: MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR](https://codepoints.net/U+00BA)

Your database character set is `US7ASCII`, this set does not support `º` thus you cannot store it.

Your DB is set to `US7ASCII` but your Java uses UTF-16.
Java sends `0x00 0xBA` to database. I don't know why but this is converted to `0xFF 0xBA` which is `ﾺ` [U+FFBA HALFWIDTH HANGUL LETTER CHIEUCH](https://codepoints.net/U+FFBA) when encoded as UTF-16.

You could do following.

- Use `NVARCHAR2` data type instead of `VARCHAR2`. Usually the National character set is a Unicode set which supports all Unicode characters.
- Migrate your database to Unicode, see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011)
- Another idea of mine was to use `°` [U+00B0: DEGREE SIGN](https://codepoints.net/U+00B0) as workaround. However it is not supported by ASCII either.